# "in God's name" usage in English

Tags: idioms, american-english

When people say "what in God's name are you doing?", I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idiom is an "intensifier". It expresses shock, horror or at least dismay at what you seem to be doing. The implication is that the speaker thinks you should not be doing what you are doing.

The reason for originally invoking God's name was to shame a religious person who would not want to do anything evil "in God's name".

This is an old-fashioned expression. In the more secular society of today, you might be just as likely to hear "What in [the] hell are you doing?" with roughly the same meaning.

Both of these are RHETORICAL QUESTIONS—said for effect, not to really ask for an answer.
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question